# Elastic Beanstalk environment variables are not reading/loading in Lumen application

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, lumen

I have deploy my lumen application v8.3.0 on Elastic Beanstalk, But I try to load the envoirnment variables frim Elastic Beanstalk properties then array is empty and no variable is loaded. Event I have try to load by using different packages i.e **vlucas/phpdotenv** and also use $_SERVER,$_ENV and getenv("APP_KEY").
I am stuck to debug this problem either it is AWS side issue or code level.

**AWS Elastic Beanstalk**

PHP 8.0 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.3.9

Lumen v8.3

```
"require": {
        "php": "^8.0",
        "dusterio/lumen-passport": "^0.3.4",
        "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "6.*",
        "illuminate/redis": "^8.79",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "^8.3.1",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^3.0",
        "league/fractal": "^0.19.2",
        "pearl/lumen-request-validate": "^1.6",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "ramsey/uuid": "^4.2",
        "tzsk/collage": "^5.1"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

It available when request go by nginx, because elasticbeanstalk save environment  on nginx. But if you use lumen/laravel queue or do something with php artisan, you can't see your environment.
Recommend this example https://github.com/rennokki/laravel-aws-eb for build application on elasticbeanstalk.